# Sharepoint 2010 public facing website, anonymous users allowed

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have enabled anonymous users on the farm and on the entire site.
I also have Windows Authentication turned on.

Whenever an anonymous user attempts to view the site, they are prompted to log in.
And they get prompted to login on every single page they view.

I would like to allow users to log in via Windows Authentication, (perhaps through a special page), but anonymous users should not get prompted to put in their password ever.

Does that mean I need to switch to forms based authentication for the entire site, or is there an option in 2010 to somehow get Windows Authentication and allowing anonymous users to live harmoniously.

Comment: "They get prompted to login on every single page they view" - if they can view the page after all, it's obviously not the page itself that requires authentication. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be because some of the file is not published. For ex, if master page, CSS stylesheet or any image is unpublished, it will prompt the user for login.

Make sure everything is published and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see if it is anything on this path http://server/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx
that it is not published.
You must publish everything

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed some of the configuration steps .So i wish if you take a look to the following article

[SP2010 Branding Tip #9 – Turn on Anonymous Access](http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/sp2010-branding-tip-9-turn-on-anonymous.html)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the Publishing Site Template for the public site and hence the default.aspx (the welcome page of all the subsites) is not published so you would need to start the approval workflow publish the pages and any other assets (master page, css, images etc)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some prepwork to set the site up using two web applications, both with different authentication methods. You can't run SharePoint effectively for Windows users and anonymous (or Forms based authentication) at the same time.

Essentialy:

1. Create your SharePoint site for internal users using Windows Authentication
2. Extend the site to a new site (using the same content database) but using anonymous or forms based authentication (whichever makes sense for you)

A MSDN article can be found here on this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648385.aspx

You can also read Andrew Connell's blog about this (he talks about Forms based authentication but you can do the same with anonymous access)
http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/HowToConfigPublishingSiteWithDualAuthProvidersAndAnonAccess.aspx

Basically you want dual authentication, Windows for one set of users and anonymous or FBA for another (and each access the site using a different URL)

Hope that helps.